# Convert Excel to CSV and Ignore Empty Cells and DropDownList in C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have the following method which loops over my Excel workbook sheet as a data table converting it to CSV via the string builder output.

On my Excel workbook I have the dropdownlist and on the output CSV these dropdownlist also are converted from XLS to CSV also when the row Excel is empty.

[image]

I have tried to check string is null or not empty but the output of CVS is empty file.

```
while (row_no < result.Tables[ind].Rows.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[ind].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csvData))
        {
            csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + "|";
        }
    }

    row_no++;
    csvData += "\n";
}
```

Question; what am I doing wrong?!

I feel like I'm so close, but its just not behaving.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

My complete code below :

```
 FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("...");
 string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("...");
 FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
 IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
 DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
 excelReader.Close();

 result.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
 string csvData = "";
 int row_no = 0;
 int ind = 0;

 while (row_no < result.Tables[ind].Rows.Count)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[ind].Columns.Count; i++)
     {
        csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + "|";    
     }

     row_no++;
     csvData += "\n";
 }

 output = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("...csv");
 newOutput = Path.GetFileName(output);
 StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false);
 csv.Write(csvData);
 csv.Close();
 csv.Dispose();
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, why do you want to convert the Excel file to CSV? It's far easier to handle dates and decimals with an Excel file than it is with CSV. The very fact you use `|` as a field separator means you've encounterd problems with decimals or commas in field data

Comment: Second, What is the input and what output do you expect? As for the output - did you store it in the correct location? What does `csvData` contain, what does `output` contain? Just create a small console application or unit test to test your code, so you don't have to bring up a web server each time and wonder where it stored the file

Comment: Your code doesn't use a StringBuilder, it just contatenates strings, resulting in a lot of memory waste. You don't need a StringBuilder when you use a StreamWriter anyway, You could just use `WriteLine` directly. Even the loop can be simplified - just use `foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)` and then use `String.Join("|",row.ItemArray)`

Comment: Finally, a quick and not-so-dirty solution would be to just use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to create a CSV file from a DataTable. CsvHelper allows using custom field and row delimiters, field qualifiers (ie double quotes) and properly exporting values that may include newlines

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you